# Why prototype of ioctl call is using unsigned long as third argument?

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, device-driver, ioctl

Below is the prototype of an ioctl call

```
long ioctl(struct file *f, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg);
```

Why third argument of an ioctl is unsigned long by default? Some times we pass a pointer to it. But it is using unsigned long.

Comment: This page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html gives a different prototype and says the third argument used to be a pointer.  Where are you getting your prototype from exactly?

Comment: The [official POSIX reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ioctl.html) shows it with ellipsis. On the other hand, POSIX states this call is only for STREAMS devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In kernel **unsigned long** is often used as a substitution for pointers, for pointers always have this size on every architecture. **Ioctls** may take an integer as an argument as well, so this makes sense here. This must be defined for each **ioctl**.

Please mind, that ioctls are deprecated and **unlocked_ioctls** must be used in current kernel versions: http://lwn.net/Articles/119652/